# How to create new group chat?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to create new group chat. I found a button to create new chat:

[image]

The problem: when I add participants to whom I already talked before in another group chat, the chat window is filled with previous discussion.

[image]

I want to create **new** blank chat with same participants.

How to correctly create new group chat with same participants?

Background: I want to organize user reported issues with unique ID in teams. Since all group chats are plain lists, my idea is to have multiple chats where title contains ID. Then me and others can switch between chats to update specific issue, continue discussions, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create new group chat you just need to click that down arrow (it's a button) to the right:

[image]

Clicking it will let to choose a new name for chat and will remove any previous chats from right pane.

Below is my previous workaround, which was easier to figure out than that finding that hidden button.

---

There is a trick to have new *blank* chat with same group you already had disccusions in past:

- create new chat;
- add participants you want;
- add **extra** participant (ensuring you didn't have conversions with same combination of of participants before);
- after chat is created - remove that extra participant.

Comment: Nice. Did my comment also work? It can help setting proper titles. Plus, it could be easily automated from Outlook VBA when it is connected to Teams.

Comment: The workaround is also the required pathway if you want to have a named chat with one other user; currently Microsoft Teams still does not allow named chats with one user out of the box, so you have to create one with 3 users and then remove the 3rd user.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is normal behavior.

In the field you typed and selected the first name (say, Julian), you can keep typing other names.
If you type and select David, and you had a previous chat with both of them, it will go to that chat. If not, it will show you a "new chat" window.

You cannot have more than one chat window with the exact same people.
So you cannot start a new chat window with the exact same people you already chatted.

Comment: All this I already know. Do you mean to say "No, it's not possible" or what? Maybe my question is not clear, but I want to have blank chat somehow.

Comment: @Sinatr - Not that way. You could try setting up various meetings with the same people, each meeting with a suitable Subject. And then chat there.
I am not sure if *all* the same features are available for both types of chat. For instance, chat in a Team allows for replying to messages, while "direct" chats or chats in calendar meetings do not.
Please let me know if this works, and if so I will add it to the answer.

Comment: This not correct; you can (even back in 2020) have multiple chats with the same people.

Comment: @TylerH: how is this possible? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @David.P You have to name the existing chat conversation with the people you want to create a new chat conversation with. Or I think you might be able to name the new chat first, I haven't tried it that way yet.

Comment: @TylerH: That doesn't seem to work. You always end up in the same chat if you specify the same people. But as a workaround you can create as many dummy meetings (with different names) as you want, then you have a new chat under a new name with the same people for each meeting.

Comment: @David.P I just did it successfully on Teams version 1.6.00.16472 on Windows 10, so it does work.

Comment: @TylerH: would you describe how this works for you? If I rename an existing chat, then start a new chat with the same participants as in the just renamed chat, I am automatically taken back to the renamed chat and not to a new chat ‍♂️

Comment: @David.P I created a new chat, set the name, and then invited all the people I currently have an existing unnamed group chat with, and it worked. You may not have the same feature capability if you're on a different (older) version or on macOS. Hard to say.

Comment: @TylerH I am also on Windows 10 with the same Teams version 1.6.00.16472 (64-bit). When I create a new chat, I can't name it until I select people. Once I select the people, I'm back in the previous chat with the same people (that chat also can't be renamed).

Comment: @David.P When you create a new chat, click on the down arrow to the far right of the recipients field to expand that section and set a new name: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K06IU.png Once you set the name, you should then be able to add the same recipients as an existing chat without it jumping into that pre-existing chat.

Comment: Bingo Tyler! OMG, I spent so much time figuring out workarounds for this, and now it's there right in my face.

Comment: @TylerH: Is there maybe also a way to have multiple chats with different chat names with ONE person?